# What's the source that Yavan/Greece is keneged choshech?

Tags: sources-mekorot, chanuka

I heard that Greece is connected to the term 'choshech' in the line "Tohu VaBohu Vechoshech al benei tehom..." ([Bereishis 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), and I heard the idea used in multiple shiurs. Just wondering where that comes from, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The source is [Bereishit Rabbah 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.2.4?lang=bi).

> וְחשֶׁךְ, זֶה גָּלוּת יָוָן, שֶׁהֶחֱשִׁיכָה עֵינֵיהֶם שֶׁל יִשְׂרָאֵל בִּגְזֵרוֹתֵיהֶן
>
> ”And darkness”: This refers to the exile imposed by Greece, who darkened the eyes of Israel with their decrees.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the Bereishis Rabbah mentioned by @JoelK it also appears in the [Yalkut Shimoni 4:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.4.9?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah&lang=bi)

> וחשך זה יון שהחשיכה עיניהן של ישראל בגזרותיה שהיתה אומרת להן כתבו על קרן השור שאין לכם חלק באלקי ישראל
>
> *And darkness this is Greece that darkened the eyes of Israel with their decrees, who said to them to write on the horn of an ox that you don't have a portion in the G-d of Israel.*

Comment: This doesn't add much as yalkut Shimoni is just a collection of Midrashim from other sources, including bereishis Rabbah. I would've added it to the other answer, personally.

Comment: That maybe the case but it adds the additional point of "who said to them to write on the horn of an ox that you don't have a portion in the G-d of Israel" which isn't mentioned in Bereishis Rabbah

Comment: [Sure it is](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.2.4). It's just the other answer for some reason left it out.