What is the problem with moral polytheism?
Ostensibly the issue with polytheism is in believing in an amoral god (or gods) that does not hold mankind to account for its (mankinds) amoral actions only caring about its (the god[s]) own personal needs eg child sacrifice etc in order to provide mankind with its own needs eg rain and fertility.
However from the fact that the "Shema" proclaims HaShem's oneness seems to indicate that even if one were to posit multiple gods (that say control different facets of nature) that are all moral and responsive—in the form of reward and punishment—to mankind for its (mankinds) moral/amoral actions it would still be problematic.
If this is accurate then what is the reason for a multiplicity of moral gods (that mimic HaShem's morals) being objectionable?

Because it's false?

There has not been "moral" polytheism. The example of greek politheism denied knowledge of moral divine laws https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119018/whats-the-source-that-yavan-greece-is-keneged-choshech Indian polytheism suggests that people mimic behavior of a certain deity, without defining divine morals.

Moral falsehood? There's moral lying in some situations such as to spare someone's feelings but no such thing as a moral falsehood where a major moral premise is based on a lie

Well, we do have this sort of multiplicity in Judaism, when we see God as both Gevura or Hesed and both are considered moral, i.e. in each situation, God can both punish you and forgive you, so both outcomes are contradictory but moral from Heavenly POV.

It looks insincere when you post a question only to show off what you just learned. It causes people to ignore you. Wait a couple of days and then answer.

Hashem's oneness is a theoretical term, in practice, we must hold that He has different emanations and works in diverse (all moral) ways simultaneously, frequently called Bhinos, Sefiros, Partzufim, Hishtalshelut, etc.

@AlBerko Food for thought in the kabbalistic realm altho admittedly daring and edgy. I'm sorry if it came across that way. That was not my intention, the suggestion I wrote only came to me after putting the question out there. Still and all appreciate the advice, should it happen again I will consider waiting.

Not necessarily Kabbalistic. When you do Viduy on Yom Kippur you invoke two different "aspects" or emanations of God, the Talmud says that God moves from one "throne" (of Din - judgment) to another (Rachamim - forgiveness), so basically there are two different faces to the "oneness" of our God. And, of course, both are morally legitimate.

@AlBerko, less that both are morally legitimate as some underlying Idea is moral, and through human that idea is expressed as Chessed in some Situations and Gevurah in others. What is that underlying Idea? Well in qabbalo, you can chase that chain up until you get to Reisha deLo IsYada, which (as the name says) is unknowable.  A dialectic between Chessed and Gevurah is the level we can emulate. And even then, Gevurah's legitimacy is as an expression of Chessed. Just as a toddler's parents stand back to let their child possibly fall on their bum because learning to walk is the greater Chessed

The most cited Meiri by a wide margin is the one where he tells you that all the laws referring to aku"m do NOT apply to polytheists whose religion teaches morality. Historically, the point of polytheistic religion was to appease the gods, and once they were paid off, you could act badly with impunity. But that is for non-Jews. (Jews have a second job: we need to be a "kingdom.of priests" and teach the rest of the world, which requires being on the right page.) But even according to the Meiro, a non-Jew who has a pantheon is still a sinner. Just not as evil as we would have otherwise assessed.

@MichaBerger I don't get it. Are those two distinctive entities or do they only "appear" as such? Does God play "good cop" and "bad cop" or is everything determined and God does not act out of those two opposing inclinations?

@AlBerko, "entities"? Are you a polytheist? What I said was, Hashem is one thing - a Provider of Good. At times the expression of it looks like Mercy, at times Justice. But that is us, projecting our limited understanding onto a pattern of Action that is bigger than our minds.

@MichaBerger I asked whether Chesed and Gevura are God's qualities/emanations or exclusively our perception. If the first, you break oneness, if the second, Chessed and Gevura are inexistent and the world is deterministic.

@AlBerko, I am saying the latter. As does the Gra's first Kelal in Asarah Kelalim. Qabbalah only discusses how Hashem appears to us, not the Godhead Itself. Beyond a negative description - that it is Ein Sof, Hashem lacks finitude. But why does that make anything deterministic? Especially since no matter how you slice it, Hashem's Action in this world isn't arbitrary. What difference does it make if we stop with not finding any patterns, find 10 patterns we cannot intergrate, 2 patterns, 13 Middos, etc...?

@AlBerko The sefiros are creations of G-d, not G-d himself. This is Judaism 101.

@MichaBerger Rabbinic discourse lacks the differentiation between experiential and empirical truths. Sun rotating the Earth is the former, Earth rotating the Sun is the latter. Speaking of emanations, are those "real" entities, that God "created" as nt mentioned, or only "seeming" qualities? You say the latter, but many, as you see, disagree. For starters, you revoke God's goodness (so God is NOT good, it APPEARS good), as well as "objective" divine morality - "it only seems bad". So if you sin "it only seems like a sin" but it's a divine plan, after all.

@AlBerko we can only take away goodness to a limit. After all, He gave us existence. So, the One is a Benefactor. As inherent as saying He is the Creator. But my point was more that any appearance of multiple explanation for Hashem's Action in this world has to be perception and not reality. Whatever word you wish to use or not use for the One Purpose.

@MichaBerger How do you deal with Sukkah 14a: אָמַר רַבִּי (אֱלִיעֶזֶר): לָמָּה נִמְשְׁלָה תְּפִלָּתָן שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים כְּעֶתֶר — ... אַף תְּפִלָּתָן שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים מְהַפֶּכֶת דַּעְתּוֹ שֶׁל הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא מִמִּדַּת אַכְזָרִיּוּת לְמִדַּת רַחֲמָנוּת.

What's the question that needs dealing? How does prayer work if כל דעבד רחמנא לטב עבד anyway? That's a bit huge for a comment chain. Prayer can change the needs of the world from a Tov that we experience as Din to one thay looks to us like Rachamim. But כל דעבד... לטב preserves ה’ אחד. Assuming He *really^ changes between two modes both denies both His Unity and his being Atemporal - למעלה מן הזמן.

After posing this question I am realizing that it seems to be a logical impossibility. To differentiate between these Gods we would need to posit either divine corporeality, which is excluded, as it limits God's power (MT, Yesodei haTorah 1:7), or some other lack (of power, knowledge etc) which would then make the entity ineligible to be a God (cf MT, ibid, 2:5-6 regarding the separate intelligences), necessarily leaving us with only one omniscient and omnipotent moral God—HaShem.

Sefer Hovos haLevavos shows that any kind of multiplicity of deities shows limitations of each. Thus none could be the original Creator.

https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_1.76.1?ven=Guide_for_the_Perplexed,_English_Translation,Friedlander(1903)&lang=bi

There is a famous chiddush of the Lubavitcher Rebbe on this. The Rambam wrote the history of Avodah Zarah into his Hilchot Avodah Zarah in Mishneh Torah. Why? Shouldn't that be in the hakdama, or in some philosophical work?
No. It's halacha to know what is the mistake of Avodah Zara. Hence he goes to great length to discuss exactly what people got wrong. Even merely offering thanks to polytheistic deities while still retaining that Hashem is the God over all is a mistake, and hence forbidden.

B"H
It's false. We're not supposed to believe in false stuff.
